# Open Source solutions for building a Traffic Management System

Tags: open-source-gis, transportation, road

I am trying to set an Open Source alternative to proprietry ITS (Intelligent Transportation Systems) The goal is to build a Traffic Management System for a middle size city center. Main requirements are:

- Visualization of road network (especially junctions) on the city map
- Managing traffic lights, cameras and other equipment on roads
- Reporting real time data from sensors, cameras (big data ?)
  Also a traffic simulation tool is required. I couldn't find an open source alternative to it because 2D and 3D simulation is needed.

Can you advice me the best FOSS4G components to build up a system like this?

Comment: Define "best". I suspect that your requirements are too vague for anyone to do that for you. What research have you already done? What is your budget and what resources and existing infrastructure do you have to work with? If a critical component does not exist, do you have the budget/time/staff to develop it yourself? Have you already done a cost-benefit analysis comparing existing commercial solutions vs. rolling your own?

Comment: In terms of open source, I'm not aware of any traffic management open source solution that is "production ready". I would suggest looking at [geoserver](http://geoserver.org/) based solution where you can just implement your own rules. A lot of the traffic management tools require massive customization to suite the client's need and I'm not aware that any current open source applications can achieve that

Comment: did you end upfinding any good solutions for the traffic management system

Comment: Unfortunatelly I couldn't

Answer (score 11):

[IRIS](http://iris.dot.state.mn.us/) is one existing open-source solution you should probably be aware of:

[image: IRIS Screenshot]

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IRIS_%28transportation_software%29):

> IRIS (Intelligent Roadway Information System) is an open-source
>   [Advanced Traffic Management System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Traffic_Management_System) (ATMS) software project
>   developed by the Minnesota Department of Transportation. It is used by
>   transportation agencies to monitor and manage interstate and highway
>   traffic. IRIS uses the GPL license.

See its [administrator guide](http://iris.dot.state.mn.us/admin_guide.html) for implementation/architecture details.

Comment: Hi, I am aware of IRIS project, but it seems to have a very weak community and limited implementation.